# Qt5.5 - Missing Compilers

Tags: android, ios, qt5, qmake, abi

I just downloaded & installed Qt 5.5 and on the "Qt Versions" tab it has a complaint about Qt 5.5.0 for iOS, it says "Not all possible target environments can be supported due to missing compilers."  If I hover the mouse over that message it says "The following ABIs are currently not supported: arm-macos-generic-mach_o-64bit"

I'm not even certain what the message is telling me, is it saying that ABI doesn't exist at all?  Or just that Qt5 can't handle it yet?

And how can I figure out which would be the appropriate compiler to install?

It is also unhappy on the Android side, it's not letting me build for Android/x86.  On the "Android" tab in the Preferences it says "Qt versions for 4 architectures are missing.  To add the Qt versions, select Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions".  I go there and it shows a whole flock of Android GCC compilers, including one for x86_64-4.9, but under the "Qt Versions" tab the only Qt for Android is for armv7.  If I click "Add" it asks me which qmake to use, and there is no qmake for android_x86.  How do I create a qmake for android/x86?